# Enviar string por Post de cliente a servidor Java Jersey

Tags: java

Intento enviar 2 string de mi cliente java a mi servidor java que usa Jersey el cliente y el servidor responden de manera correcta (code 200),

> Codigo del Servidor

```
@POST
@Path("eliminar")
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, ("text/plain") }) 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public String eliminar(
        @FormDataParam("primero") String primero,
        @FormDataParam("segundo") String segundo){  
    System.out.println("recibiendo primero "+primero+ " segundo "+segundo);
    return "Rastalovely";
}
```

> Codigo del Cliente

```
package eliminar;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Limpio {
    final static String URL = "http://localhost:8080/restdemo/jaxrs/customers/eliminar";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String crlf = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        try {
            String boundary = "--" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "--";
            String parametros="primero=primero&segundo=segundo";        
            byte[] postDataBytes = parametros.toString().getBytes();

            URL url = new URL(URL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            DataOutputStream request = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());    
            request.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);
            request.writeBytes(parametros);
            System.out.println("responseCode " + connection.getResponseCode());

            //Aqui java retorna
            BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while((line=in.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(line);
            }
            in.close();
            System.out.println("salida "+sb.toString());            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Los resultados:
Al correr el cliente obtengo en la consola del servidor las variables como nulas y del lado del cliente si recibe el mensaje del servidor.

Por lo que nose si la manera en que envio las variables son las correctas.

Answer (score 2):

Estás enviando la información tal como se enviaría en un petición HTTP normal; pero quieres trabajar con `multipart/form-data`.

El formato de tu mensaje debería ser algo como:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=DEADBEEF
--DEADBEEF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="primero"

primero
--DEADBEEF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="segundo"

segundo

--DEADBEEF--
```

A parte del obvio cambio de los parámetros, un par de apuntes:

- Estás usando `multipart/form-data` pero no parece necesario. A no ser que más adelante lo vayas a usar (para enviar adjuntos, por ejemplo), yo votaría por eliminarlo.
- A no ser que haya incompatibilidades técnicas o legales, o se trate de un ejercicio, siempre es bueno usar alguna librería que ya se encargue de la gestión a bajo de nivel, como [HttpComponents de Apache](https://hc.apache.org/)
- Parece que no estás cerrando el mensaje `"--" + delimitador + "--"`.
- No digo que sea un error, pero yo no pondría "--" como parte del delimitador.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda he publicado la manera en que resolví mi problema

Answer (score 0):

Después de investigar y usar Java Jersey como cliente, puede resolver mi problema, a continuación publico mi respuesta.

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.file.FileDataBodyPart;

public class principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                String URL="http://localhost:8080/restdemo/jaxrs/customers/upload";
                Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();
                FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("MyFile", new File("C:/Users/Rastalovely/Desktop/imagen.png"));
                FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
                FormDataMultiPart multipart = (FormDataMultiPart) formDataMultiPart
                        .field("llave1", "campo1")
                        .field("llave2", "campo2")
                        .bodyPart(filePart);
                WebTarget target = client.target(URL);
                String json = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.entity(multipart, multipart.getMediaType()), String.class);
                System.out.println("answer :"+json);
                formDataMultiPart.close();
                multipart.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
    }
}
```